# .htcaccess exclude folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i tried to exclude some folder from mod_rewrite, i have searched and try all of them.
but, it didn't work. i use it on localhost.
this is how my .htaccess file looks like.

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

i have tried this few advises, but it didn't solved the problem.
can someone assist me? assuming the directory i want to exclude is folder.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/.*$
RewriteRule ^/folder($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^folder($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(folder|folder/.*)$
RewriteRule ^(folder)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(folder)/
```

i guess, i just running out of options, since i have tried all of them? is there any mistake, that i did here?
i try to rewrite the root and also for one subdirectory.. so i want to exclude the directory.

Comment: What if in the subfolder you are trying to reach you create a .htaccess with `RewriteEngine On` in it?

Comment: didn't work either... i want to have some url like this
"http://www.example.com/article/1/whatever-title", but when i try to access this path "http://www.example.com/folder/" it gives me HTTP error 500...

Comment: it's weird... i try to put .htaccess file on the root folder, which in "localhost/root/", and i try another url like "localhost/root/whatever/whatever/", it will be on "localhost/root/index.php", and when i try to access a directory "localhost/root/test/", it shows me the "test" directory, there's nothing there just some folder. and i can access the subfolder inside the directory, which contains a htaccess file. it makes me even more curiously. cause i try the same for the subdirectory, that i want to access and it didn't work. "localhost/root(htaccess)/test/oop(htaccess)/user(htaccess)"

Comment: `RewriteRule ^folder($|/) - [L]` should work. Just be sure you place it **in front** of the other (existing) rules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Cheesemacfly & Gerben, it works actually with or without extra Rewriterule. all i did just put the same htaccess file on the subdirectory, just like Cheesemacfly suggested. the problem actually is there are some error on my script which make it didn't work.